# MySQL "join on like" does not utilize INDEX

Tags: mysql, sql

DB - **MySQL 5.7**

I have a relatively big table which has to be joined with it self, based on 'hierarchical' index.

So the joinable 'id' field is VARCHAR and looks like
1/222
1/222/333
1/222/444
1/222/444/555

Table creation command:

```
CREATE TABLE `referrals` (
  `id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `commission` decimal(32,16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000000000',
  `commission_currency_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`level`,`commission_currency_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

To retrieve data based on level I've planned to use a command like:

```
-- Does not utilize the index
select  r1.id,
        sum(r1.commission),
        sum(r2.commission) as commissionAcc,
from    referrals r1
left join referrals r2
on r2.id like concat(r1.id, '/%')
where r1.id like concat('10000', '/%') and r1.`level` = 1
group by r1.id
limit 10;
```

I have suddenly found, that left join referrals r2 on r2.id like concat(r1.id, '/%') just do not utilize the index.But if I replace r1.id with a string in like statement the indexes are used

```
-- Utilizes the index
select  r1.id,
        sum(r1.commission),
        sum(r2.commission) as commissionAcc,
from    referrals r1
left join referrals r2
on r2.id like concat('10000/10001', '/%')
where r1.id like concat('10000', '/%') and r1.`level` = 1
group by r1.id
limit 10;
```

I just don't get why. I have also tried:

```
-- Does not utilize the index
left join referrals r2
on left(r2.id, 6) = r1.id
```

No success. Force Index does not help as well. The only solution I see is to create a logic dependent on genereated columns, but such approach is going to take a huge amount of space.

Are there any workarounds to make MySQL to use indexes in this case? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Such string functions are pretty much going to kill index usage.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "like" with wildcard on right side of the query string is totally acceptable to be used with index. MySQL utilizes the index until the point when it has to join on parameter taken out of DB.

Comment: . . That applies to *constant* values.  Some databases may recognize this for calculated values, but MySQL does not have the most sophisticated optimizer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are totally right. Still previously I could cope with such semi-unexpected mysql decisions, but not this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on exactly the same problem. I have a hierarchy of folders, which I store internally with the adjacency list model (see Joe Celko, trees and hierarchies in sql for smarties).

My solution was to split up a single query with JOIN into two separate requests: First get the parent folder, then select all children by querying the column which contains the full path with LIKE 'PATHOFPARENT%' which then uses the index.

In your case it may be necessary to create table locks to ensure integrity.